# .JS file security, how to stop them being readable

Tags: jquery, html

I'm SURE I'm going to sound like a total .... here but I just have to ask!

We are using Stackmob to be the backend of our mobile app we are developing, I've been through the samples and it's all good (using xcode etc.). That part is fine, as far as a sample goes.

I wanted to get access to the data that was stored through a web application so I also grabbed down the sample files, index.html and app.js files (thats what it gave me), I ran it and bingo, up came my data, I could add and remove entries, I refreshed the mobile app and as if by magic, it appeared.

So, my question...I simply put these two files on my hostgator LAMP server and ran them, great, all appeared as 'normal'. I then right clicked and inspected the page and all my connection string and app code was there for all to see, if anyone was interested.

It's a pretty big security issue obviously. So, I mentioned this to my developer and he said we couldn't use that method of connecting using JQuery (i think it is) but I'm really not sure if it's right. Surely there is a way to encrypt this data or place it in a directory so it's not viewable? I've searched the net and HTML5/JQUERY/CSS is everywhere, all of that can't be unsecure??

Just needed to ask for my next step in learning this stuff and if there is a nice link for beginners around how this is accomplished?

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Regards,

Ken

Comment: Sorry, I do not see a big point in what you raise as an issue. Whilst it is true that a user who has access to some application can see bits of that application and the data he applies it upon this does _not_ mean  that *anyone* can see that data. Two things are important: 1. that the data transferred via network is encrypted (_really_ encrypted, not just obfuscated) and that data stored persistently is encrypted. If working on a shared system then also the data in memory must be encrypted. There is no security issue in a user seeing his own data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what parts you are trying to secure. Most applications consist of both client-side and server-side code. The client-side code consists of the HTML, CSS, JavaScript that gets sent down to and executes on the client, as well as the native application that runs on the user's device (such as the native Android app and iOS app). The server-side code is, as the name implies, all the code that runs on the server (including any associated databases and such). You can't really secure the client-side code (though you can use obfuscation to make it  worthless to use as the basis for building any new app).

For any user data that you are sending to the client, you want to make sure that it is only accessible to the authenticated user. For that, you can issue a token from the server to the client when the user has authenticated and require that subsequent requests for the user's data include the token. Nothing, though, stops the user from sharing the data that they can view/see on the client.

**Punchline**
If there is code that you want to keep secret, make it server-side rather than client-side code. For example, if you want to keep how you fetch or compute something secret, then don't fetch/compute it directly on the client; issue a query to your server, and let the server do the fetch/computation, instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bite..

Trying to secure javascript is like trying to convince Obama he is actually a Republican.

Then again, there was a cool article on obfuscation I read the other day ( http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2014/02/cryptography-breakthrough/ ).

You could always read up on the research paper they're talking about and create an obfuscation routine that mangles your JS code so badly that it either won't work or would be tougher to decode than just running YUI compressor on it is =)